# Auto create Nextgen Gallery on post creation

Tags: php, functions, gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery, automation

I was wondering if there is a way to create a nextgen gallery with a function, so that I can hook that into my front end post creation setup. The gallery could be completely empty or be created with the featured image of the created post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just trying to get a featured post slider. If this is the case, you could go with a much more robust and expandable option like Nivo slider. You'd have to code it into your theme yourself to get your desired result (shows recent posts automatically), but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Thanks Matt. No, I'm not interested in a slider, but in the the automatic creation of nextgen galleries each time I create a certain post type. Not the display, but actually put the gallery in the DB. Then to add images to the DB too without going through the Nextgen interface in the backend. I use Gravity Forms to create the post and then I would like to create a nextgen gallery for that post. I have not used nextgen for a long time, but I will look at the code myself soon and see if I can make any sense of it...
In the meantime someone might have done this thing before.